# Where are key press scripts stored?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, execute-command

When I hit the Volume Up multimedia key, I receive the following output from `xev`.

```
KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x91, subw 0x0, time 100844850, (1037,434), root:(1102,486),
    state 0x10, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Where is the command `XF86AudioRaiseVolume` stored? How can I run it, say, through the terminal?

Comment: What makes you think it is a command?  I don't know, but I would assume it's a constant (ie, an integer) passed on to the event handler.  I'd guess you would need a way to trigger the event handler with those parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the definition of all XF86 keys here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/x11proto/tree/XF86keysym.h (or installed on your system in `/usr/include/X11/XF86keysym.h`, if you installed `x11proto-core-dev`)

To run it from the terminal, just install `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

and run:

```
xdotool key XF86AudioRaiseVolume
```